# Serial communication by USB cable

Tags: networking

I am trying to make serial port communication at 115200 / 8 N with my customized hardware. 
It works fine with windows as OS on PC/Laptop and teraterm as application.
The same connection misbehaves and does not respond many a times with Minicom on UBUNTU 10.04 as well as 16.04
The connection uses standard USB port on PC side and MICRO USB on device side.

Comment: Keep in mind 10.04 is no longer supported, and we cannot provide support for it here, we can only provide support for actually supported releases.

Answer (score 0):

Try `screen`, it can connect to a serial port.

```
screen <serial_port> <baud_rate>
```